# Does Internet Explorer (still) remove empty elements from DOM?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, legacy

At least at one point in the past, Internet Explorer would remove empty elements from the DOM.

So the elements:

```
<div id="something"></div>
<span></span>
```

Would never appear, could not be targeted by JavaScript, etc.

The common workaround was:

```
<div id="something">&nbsp;</div>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
```

**Do any non-EOL versions of Internet Explorer still have this behaviour?**

What versions of Internet Explorer have/had this behaviour, or was it a myth? (The advice was common when IE6 was around)

Comment: Just so people don't think I'm crazy, this person believes it too!
http://www.f15ijp.com/2010/11/internet-explorer-not-rendering-empty-div-correctly/

Comment: Like the bug report you linked in a comment, that's about *rendering* the element, not removing it from the DOM. And even IE6 renders a div with nothing in it but with a background and height just fine (I just checked), so that blog post seems highly suspect.

Comment: *(Sorry, linked in an answer below, not a comment.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been doing web development off and on since 1996, and I've never seen IE do this, nor heard anyone say that it did.

I happen to have an old Windows 2000 VM lying around with IE6 on it, so I fired it up and tried it: No, it doesn't remove those elements.

I'm quite certain no non-EOL version of IE does this, and fairly certain no EOL'd version did. :-)

Answer (score -1):

According to this [bugzilla entry](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33244), 18 years ago Netscape Navigator 4 had this problem with empty *table cells* in quirks mode.

This has no relevance today but might be the source of the rumour.

Comment: That's not what that bug report says. It says it didn't **show** table cells with no content (e.g., didn't show background color, borders, etc.), not that it **removed** them. (And indeed that was the case, also with IE and even Firefox for a while.)